# Inner product issues

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

**STATEMENT:** Suppose V is a finite dimensional vector space with an inner product $\langle *,*\rangle$. And $\phi :V\rightarrow V^*$ is the isomorphism $\phi(v)=\langle v,*\rangle$ The inner product, together with the isomorphism $\phi$, define an inner product on $V^*$.

**QUESTION:** What is the particular inner product that is induced on $V^*$? Are they talking about the inner product $\langle u,v\rangle_V=\langle\phi(u),\phi(v)\rangle_{V^*}$?

Comment: Sure.  More explicitly, for any $f,g \in V^*$, define $\langle f, g \rangle_{V^*} = \langle \phi^{-1}(f), \phi^{-1}(g) \rangle_V$.

Comment: Alright thanks.

Comment: @S.S There's a little more to this. How do you know $\phi$ is an isomorphism? Linearity and injectivity are easy, but how do you do surjectivity? It depends on the fact that $V$ is finite dimensional, from which you can conclude that dim($V$) = dim($V$*) and therefore injectivity implies surjectivity. It's not immediately obvious without this chain of logic, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @user4894 This is referenced and proved in Lang's Real and Functional Analysis book page 104 in the chapter Hilbert Spaces.

Comment: @S.S Just curious, is there a more direct way to show surjectivity? Or is it via the proof outline I gave?

Comment: The injectivity proof seems to be the shortest since your working with finite dimensional vector spaces, but I can't say for certain it is the shortest.